# Decorators - Function With Parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

why do we pass the parameters to the wrapper function too?

```
def shout(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return fn(*args, **kwargs).upper()
    return wrapper

@shout
def greet(name):
    return f"Hi Iam {name}"

print(greet('Hoss'))
```

why not just in fn() (i mean inside the shout function)

Comment: Because you would get an error otherwise: `TypeError: greet() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'`

Comment: Okay, i know its the syntax :D
but also why ?

Comment: No, it's not the syntax, it's the missing function arguments.

Comment: So why we have passed to the wrapper function ???
why we didn't pass it to the fn() only ?

Comment: Because you would get an error otherwise: `TypeError: wrapper() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: I know that I will get an error... but why I will get this error.. this is a little bit confusing to me :D.
i have passed the parameters to the fn()
why i should also pass the parameters to the wrapper function!

Comment: Without receiving any arguments in `wrapper` you have no arguments you can pass to `fn`.

Comment: So is wrapper function is just a bridge for fn?

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, where would you get these arguments from? They don't appear out of nowhere and magically jump into fn(...).